# Problem with inequality $\min (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$

Tags: inequality

let $0\le x_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, and $a_i=1+(i-1)d$, $d\in[0,2],\forall i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, show that
$$(1+a_n)\left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\right)^2\ge 2n \min(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i\right)$$

$n=1,2,3$ is not hard to prove it,I am unsure what to do from here, I know I somehow need to compare a form of this expression to $\min{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)}$?, but how? Am I on the right lines?but I don't have any idea how to start proving it

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: $(x_1+\cdots+x_n) \geq n \cdot \min(x_1.\cdots+x_n)$.. for $d=2$, $1+a_n=2n$ and for $d=0$ all $a_i=1$ and $1+a_n=2$. Also $a_n\geq a_i$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, by the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), the sum on the right side is maximized when $x_i$'s are arranged in ascending order.  Thus, it suffices to show the case with $x_1 \le x_2 \le \cdots \le x_n$.  In other words, we wish to show
$$
(1+a_n)(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)^2
\ge
2 \, n \, x_1 \, (a_1 \, x_1 + \cdots + a_n \, x_n).
$$

Second, suppose $x_2 > x_1$, we can replace $x_n$ by $x_n + x_2 - x_1$, and then replace $x_2$ by $x_1$.  This would leave sum $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$ unchanged, while increasing the sum on the right-hand side.  We can also do this for $x_3, \dots, x_{n-1}$.  This means we only need to show the case with $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{n-1} \le x_n$.  Define $\Delta \equiv x_n - x_1$, we only need to show that
\begin{align}
(1+a_n)(n \, x_1 + \Delta)^2
\ge
2 \, n \, x_1 \, (a_1 \, x_1 + \cdots + a_n \, x_1 + a_n \, \Delta) \\
=
2 \, n \, x_1 \, \left[
\frac{1}{2}(1 + a_n) \, n \, x_1 + a_n \, \Delta\right].
\end{align}

But this inequality is obvious, for
\begin{align}
(1+a_n)(n \, x_1 + \Delta)^2
&=
(1 + a_n) \, n \, x_1 \, n \, x_1
+2 (1 + a_n) \, n \, x_1 \, \Delta
+ (1 + a_n) \, \Delta^2 \\
&\ge
\frac 1 2 (1 + a_n) 2 \, n \, x_1 \, n \, x_1
+2 \, a_n \, n \, x_1 \, \Delta \\
&=2 \, n \, x_1 \left[
\frac{1}{2}(1+a_n) \, n \, x_1 + a_n \, \Delta
\right].
\end{align}
Q.E.D.